# Version of Linux with a command prompt?

Tags: linux, command-line, terminal

What is the name of the software for Linux which has a command prompt (terminal)?

I am trying to download Linux with command prompt so that I can run it on [VMWare](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VMware), using a sandbox.

Comment: All distros have terminals.

Answer (score 9):

Most Linux distros are capable of running with a command line. If you want one that is *purely* a command line then you just need to deselect all the graphical tools when you install.

Answer (score 6):

Just about *any* Linux can run from a command line.

Similarly, just about any Linux can run a complete desktop from your VMWare sandbox.

SUGGESTION:
Try downloading a pre-built VMWare appliance of Ubuntu server from here:

http://www.thoughtpolice.co.uk/vmware/

Answer (score 3):

In some sense Linux is "all terminal", that is, the GUI runs atop the command line. If you remember the Windows 3.1-era, you'd boot your computer to DOS and then run Windows as a command, it's much the same with Linux today. The desktop that most distros run (KDE, GNOME) is just another program like, for example, Firefox.

You can get a terminal in a couple of easy ways. Most desktop environments (have a terminal):

- GNOME has `gnome-terminal`
- KDE has `konsole`
- *almost anything else* has `xterm`

Since a desktop environment is running "atop" the command line, you can also grab an already-running terminal by pressing `Ctrl+Alt+F1`, that is press Control, Alt and the F1 key at the same time. To get back to the graphical session, press `Ctrl+Alt+F7`.

To answer your question then, *any* type of linux will do, but since you haven't any interest in running a desktop environment, you can safely get any "server" type of distro, [Ubuntu Server](http://www.ubuntu.com/server), for example.

Comment: XFCE has Terminal and LXDE has LXTerminal.

Comment: And you can always install something else, I use urxvt-256color

Comment: Yeah, `urxvt` is a nice choice over `xterm` to get Unicode!

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a minimal Linux distribution without a GUI, snag the Debian `netinst` CD image.  Install it, don't select any "tasks" or collections of packages, and you'll have a very minimal Linux system with pretty much nothing else but a shell and `nano`.  Fits under 1GByte of hard drive space and works nicely if you want a super-minimal Linux VM.  Plus just about any software you want is just an `apt-get` away.