# Command line Linux OS using the sandbox for learning the Linux command prompt

Tags: linux

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Version of Linux with a command prompt?](https://superuser.com/questions/215541/version-of-linux-with-a-command-prompt)

Which software of Linux to use for command line running? Since I am using MySQL to run from Linux and want to run Linux, which software to download in Linux? There are multiple ones. Can I run .sh scripts and learn how to operate on Linux using the command line? Also use MySQL as backend on Linux?

Comment: Link your accounts instead of creating a new question.

Answer (score 1):

Any [distro of linux/unix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_distribution) has command line access. It's called the terminal. Not all distros come with a GUI by default, so you will encounter the terminal upon installation of the distro.

Do you already have a distro of linux installed and available?

What are you trying to accomplish, exactly?

Are you looking for a SSH client for remote access, like [Putty](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/)?